# i am not getting the report of all the executed test cases through programmatic TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created the object of TestNG and using to execute the test cases.

if(parameters.getValue().ExecutionType.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))  {
//This yes is coming through excel file which is marked as flag for the testcase name

```
package ForNewFramework;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class CustomizeSuitetorunTestNG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();

        suite.setName("TmpSuite");
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
         test.setName("TmpTest");

        GetExcelInMap object  = new GetExcelInMap();
        try {
            Map<String, SetterGetterOfExcelValue> SuitParameters = object.getExcel();


        for(Map.Entry<String, SetterGetterOfExcelValue> parameters: SuitParameters.entrySet())
        {


        String ClassName = "ForNewFramework."+parameters.getValue().getTestCaseName();


        if(parameters.getValue().ExecutionType.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))  
        {

          List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
          classes.add(new XmlClass(ClassName));
          test.setXmlClasses(classes) ;

          List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
          suites.add(suite);
          TestNG tng = new TestNG();
          tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
          tng.run();
        }

        }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }

This my class which is running testng.
I am creating the object of this class "GetExcelInMap" where i am getting the data from excel and saved to the variables by using setter and getter method.

In Class CustomizeSuiterun:
I am running three classes from the package name "ForNewFramework", where the names of the classes and in excel both are same so i am loading the names of the classes from excel.

My testng.xml created like this in index.html:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="TmpSuite">
      <test name="TmpTest">
        <classes>
          <class name="ForNewFramework.ThirdTestCase"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- TmpTest -->
    </suite> <!-- TmpSuite -->
```

Here, my first and second test was executed but in report, only last executed class is mentioned. The execution report of the second class and first class is overridden by Third class execution.

It executes the scripts perfectly.
I am using default report of TestNG, where i am not getting the report of all the executed test cases by making Flag as "Yes" in excel. 
I am only getting the output in index.hmtl file of the **last class file which is executed in last through programmatic TestNG.**
Could you please suggest how can i get the report of all the test cases which are marked as Yes in Flag.

Please let me know, am able to provide proper code or required information to you so that you can able to help me.

Comment: Could you provide more code? For example, I'd like to see the loop with all "Yes" tests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are running it immediately after adding the class. You need to add all classes and then run at the end. So what is happening is that it is executing 3 separate xml suites. You need to take the run outside the loop

```
     if(parameters.getValue().ExecutionType.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))  
            {

              List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
              classes.add(new XmlClass(ClassName));
              test.setXmlClasses(classes) ;

              List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
              suites.add(suite);


            }

            }


       TestNG tng = new TestNG();
                  tng.setXmlSuites(suites); 
tng.run();      
 }
```

Make the neccessary changes as you have to declare suites outside the loop.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely correct.
Also, I removed " Array list" from the "If" condition and loop.
List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

Thank so much (y) :)

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava. Np . Please accept it as answer.